# r stat - sum up based on colums attributes

Tags: r

I'm new to R-stat. Basically, I have this dataframe :

```
Group.1 Group.2    x
1      111       1    2
2      211       1   69
3      212       1  123
4      311       1    8
5      314       1    1
6      315       1    1
7      111       2  875
8      112       2  318
9      211       2 1624
10     212       2 1754
11     311       2  734
12     312       2   43
13     313       2   26
14     314       2   48
15     315       2   38
16     316       2   51
17     323       2   11
18     324       2    4
19     325       2   20
20     326       2    5
21     111       3  417
22     112       3  127
23     211       3  271
24     212       3  342
25     311       3   54
26     312       3    4
27     314       3    2
28     315       3    3
29     316       3    7
30     324       3    2
31     325       3    3
32     326       3    1
...
```

I get all this by calling the following function :

```
data <- aggregate(smp$IPONDL, by=list(smp$ACHL, smp$CMBL),FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)

data$x <- round(data$x, digits = 0)
```

I want all Group.1 values > 315 to be summed up.
I've tried with the following code :

```
data$x <- c(data[1,]$x, data[2,]$x, data[3,]$x, data[4,]$x, data[5,]$x, data[6,]$x + data[7,]$x + data[8,]$x + data[9,]$x + data[10,]$x + data[11,]$x + data[12,]$x + data[13,]$x + data[14,]$x + data[15,]$x)
```

But it does not work coorectly, probably because I'm working with index (and not value). It returns same values for any Group.2 attribute value. I want distinct value for each Group.2 id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a logical vector on the 'Group.1' values and subset the 'x' values based on that and get the `sum`

```
sum(data$x[data$Group.1>315])
```

---

If efficiency is a problem, then `data.table` can be also used

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[Group.1>315, .(Sum = sum(x))]
```

#### Update

If we need this grouped by 'Group.2'

```
setDT(data)[Group.1>315, .(Sum = sum(x)), by = Group.2]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This sum up all variables without distinction on Group.2 variables. I'd like to get the sum for Group.2 = 1, Group.2 = 2, and so one ...

Answer (score 5):

With the `dplyr` library :

```
data %>% filter(Group.1 > 315) %>% group_by(Group.2) %>% summarise(sum = sum(x))
```

Comment: It also works! But as akrun proposal, this sum up all variables without distinction on Group.2 variables. I'd like to get the sum for Group.2 = 1, Group.2 = 2, and so one ...

Comment: Updated with a group_by function  ;)

Comment: Both solutions work. Thanks a lot